# Test Extjs 6.5 modern application in browser

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern

I am new in using the latest version of ExtJs and I have a small app project created using Sencha Architect based on the Login example in ExtJS 6.5 modern. However, I cannot check if the UI is working. For the previous versions of ExtJS, I just open the index.html page, but for 6.5 modern, it does not work. Thanks for the help

Comment: Then your app does not work. My 6.5-modern application is still working in browser...

Comment: Your application isn't loading properly. Make sure all includes(requires) especially are in their respective files